# Sort arraylist in X different ways at the same time

Tags: java, sorting, oop, design-patterns

If I have an ArrayList of custom objects which I need to be able to display them in various sortings (e.g. 4 types of sort so 4 comparators to use the proper member variables of the objects for the sorting) what is the most efficient way to do it?
I don’t think having e.g. 4 array lists of the objects sorted according to a specific comparator is optimal.
Is there another more efficient way than this?
Please note that I would need to have these objects sorted at the same time as they will be presented in the same page. So I can’t sort on demand

Comment: Where do you display those? Shouldn't the view do the sorting (as when clicking on a header in a data grid)?

Comment: you can implement 4 different `Comparator`, but AFAIK you cannot have same `List` ordered in various wais...

Comment: @Philippe:In a UI in android device. Well the view can do the sorting but I wanted to avoid 4 different sorted lists of same objects if possible

Comment: If you can use Java8, you could check out these foils http://2016.java-forum-stuttgart.de/_data/D4_Wiedeking.pdf ... they are from the Java Forum in Stuttgart last week, and if you turn to pages 55 (and before) ... you will find a complete example how to use lambdas to sort on various properties of whatever class. Not much text on those foils; so I guess you have to figure yourself if they are helpful to you.

Comment: I'd go with different `Comparators` as suggested by @JordiCastilla and if you hit performance issues go with the second option to keep sorted lists which reference the same objects in all the lists

Comment: @Philippe my comment was just to point out the (IMO) impossibility of sorting same object in various ways **at the same time**... But I like more you option of sorting data in the view (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

You could have different index arrays containing integers that are interpeted as indices of your original `ArrayList`. These can be sorted in different ways.

To access the list elements, use something like this:

```
list.get(index1.get(i));
```

Comment: That means I would need to have 4 sorted lists of integers representing the indexes of the array list. Considering that the arraylist stores references of the objects and we essentially during sort we move around the references is there a big difference between the approaches?

Comment: @Jim: Yes, you're right. In Java there is no significant difference. That being said, I doubt that there is any significantly more efficient way to fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that [FlyWeight design pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/flyweight_pattern.htm) could match your expectations.

Flyweight pattern is primarily used to reduce the number of objects created and to decrease memory footprint and increase performance. This type of design pattern comes under structural pattern as this pattern provides ways to decrease object count thus improving the object structure of application.

As you have your objects in an ArrayList, you can build up as many ArrayLists as different kinds of sorts you need for storing flyweight objects (basically id, order).